# Angular ui-router with spa using sticky states not preserving scroll position on first back button

Tags: angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I'm creating an Angular mobile SPA app and part of the requirements have a substantial amount of list >> details pages. After they filter to populate the list, they can click on the item to go to a details page for it (with crud options if allowed, which rules out just using a modal). I'm saving the relevant data and things in a service, but this does not help maintain the scroll position and ui-router-extras sticky state seems like it would be ideal. I'm using requirejs as well, in case that's relevant. Also, I am using a Kendo ListView bound with a kendo.dataSource if that is relevant.

I've implemented it, but I'm not sure I've done it correctly. I scroll down and click on a list item and it goes to the details. When I click the back button (a directive that uses `$window.history.back();`, although I tried using `$state.go` and it did the same thing), it will go back and used the "cached" version, but will be at the top of the list. If I scroll down and click on another item and then go back, it will maintain the scroll position like I expect.

I turned on `$stickyStateProvider.enableDebug(true);` and the output looks identical from the first to the subsequent calls.

Here's my states config:

```
return app.config(function ($stateProvider, $stickyStateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stickyStateProvider.enableDebug(true);
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
        var $state = $injector.get("$state");
        $state.go("home");
    });
    $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/home.html',
        controller: 'homeController',
        controllerAs: "vm"
    })
    .state('cmmenu', {
        url: '/cmmenu',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/cmmenu.html',
        controller: 'cmmenuController',
        controllerAs: "vm"
    })
    .state('areainquiry', {
        //sticky: true,
        abstract: true,
        url: '/areainquiry',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/areainquiry.html'
    })
    .state('areainquiry.list', {
        url: '/areainquirylist',
        views: {
            'areainquirylist@areainquiry': {
                templateUrl: 'app/views/areainquirylist.html',
                controller: 'areainquirylistController',
                controllerAs: "vm"
            }
        },
        sticky: true,
        deepStateRedirect: true
    })
    .state('areainquiry.details', {
        url: '/areainquirydetails/:areaInquiryId',
        views: {
            'areainquirydetails@areainquiry': {
                templateUrl: 'app/views/areainquirydetails.html',
                controller: 'areainquirydetailsController',
                controllerAs: "vm"
            }
        }
    })
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/login.html',
        controller: 'loginController',
        controllerAs: "vm"
    });
})
```

Here is the areainquiry.html that is the abstract parent view:

```
<div ui-view="areainquirylist"  ng-show="$state.includes('areainquiry.list')"></div>
<div ui-view="areainquirydetails" ng-show="$state.includes('areainquiry.details')"></div>
```

Here is the code that is opening this screen. I do not have a named view in my index.html and all views up to areainquiry.html are using the root un-named view (I gave it a name "body" and changed all of them to use it, but it worked the same):

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    <a class="btn btn-default fullwidth" ui-sref="areainquiry.list">
        <span class="{{ vm.areaInquiryButtonIcon }}"></span>
        <br />
        {{ vm.areaInquiryButtonText }}
    </a>
</div>
```

I was trying to figure out a way to do it without the abstract state and just through a parent areainquiry and child areainquiry.detail, but couldn't get it working that way, so went this route.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. It is working. I'm not sure how I fixed it. I was working through another issue (had to do with a factory service), so I'm assuming that fixed it.